# How to handle different structure of same Entity in Hibernate L2 cache with Coherence for caching

Tags: web-services, hibernate, oracle-coherence

I am using Hibernate L2 cache with Coherence for caching in two different web services.

**Scenario**

- First web service has an entity class `Employee` with 5 fields
- Second web service has the same entity class `Employee` but with 3 fields.

Both are pointing to same table/schema and the package hierarchy is also same.

Now when fresh request for `employeeId=1` comes to second web service, it fetches from the value from the database and caches the 3 columns; keeps the other 2 as null.

Now when a request for `employeeId=1` comes from the first web service, it directly fetches from cache by providing 3 columns and returns the other 2 as null, even though in the database the 2 columns have non-null values.

Is there a way by which I can force it get these column from database?

**Approaches already tried**

1. If I keep the columns in both the web services as same the problem goes away but this is not a acceptable solution in my scenario.
2. I tried added different **serialVersion** but it doesn't work.
3. Keeping the fully qualified name different works, but this is force us add overhead to performing manual eviction

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [Evolvable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/coh.371/e22843/com/tangosol/io/Evolvable.html) interface for this, which will allow you to insert an object into the grid that is both forward and backward compatible.  You just need to ensure that Second Webservice sets a lower version than First.